# Need to call perl script from javascript

Tags: ajax, perl, jscript

I have written a perl script I can access from a URL:
   **https://hostname/myweb/myScript.pl?id=1234&stg=13**
I get the proper results using the URL

In javascript/jscript, I have tried loading the script (`$('#element').load()`) - I've tried full ajax calls within a function:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/myweb/myScript.pl',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      'id' : '1234',
      'stg' : '13'
    }
  });
```

I am not having any success.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

M

Comment: Crossposted to [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11107619).

Comment: *I am not having any success* - It would be really helpful to know what this means. What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Does nothing seem to happen? Is there an error message (perhaps in the web server error log)? Does your computer explode?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your perl script expect a get request not a post request
try:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/myweb/myScript.pl?id=1234&stg=13',
    type: 'get'
  });
```

if you would like use data you can do it this way:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/myweb/myScript.pl',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
      'id' : '1234',
      'stg' : '13'
   }

  });
```

this should work too